# How to get run of osmAnd in android studio

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I download osmAnd form github from this link : [link](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand).
My problem is that when i want to run this project in android studio i get this error [An Image from my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTxYC.png) .
Please help , This is very important to me .
Thank you .

Comment: cross-posted: https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/3267

Comment: what do you mean by this link ? I created this issue but i didn't get answer overthere and after that i decided to ask my question here ! by the way thankyou for your answer

Comment: It helps people to see whether this question has already been answered otherwise to not waste their time. You should include such links in your question.

Comment: Thank you i'll do that from now